# Current panel in jqmobi app

Tags: jqmobi

I am porting a mobile app from jQueryMobile to jqMobi and am looking for a way to determine the currently viewed panel.  In jQuery they had

```
$.mobile.activePage
```

Does jqMobi have something similar, or do i need to track it myself?

Comment: Hello. I'm doing the same thing. But i couldnt make it worked. Can you share me the function to get current panel in jqmobi app ? I asked a question here but couldn't get the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492193/determine-active-panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property called "activeDiv" that you can use - it is the raw DOM node.

```
$.ui.activeDiv
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will give that a shot.  How did you find that?  I dont see it listed in the UI docs...

Comment: note - I'm the author

It's not really documented (my fault).  I'm in the process of revamping the docs to have better examples.

Comment: Found this also by chance in the console... this is the ultimate answer i guess, so why is it not marked as such? Full Kudo's from my side! Hopefully jqMobi and it's outstanding team will thrive well in their new home.