# Determine Active Panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jqmobi, appframework

I'm on a phonegap project.

I do my project with JQMobi (new name is Intel's App Framework)..

On this project i want to determine the visible/active panel to startup my functions according to it.

Here is what i've tried ;

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function () {
        var id = $.ui.activeDiv[0].id;

        if ($.ui.activeDiv[0].id=="contents01"){
             getLive();        
            }
        });

       function getLive(){
          alert('on live page!');
        }
```

how can i do this in jqmobi/app framework ?

i used this in jquery mobile and it was working.

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function () {
    var id = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;

    if (id=="home"){
         getHomePage();        
    }
    else.....
```

Waiting your answers.

Thanks.

Comment: @kgms21-May be you can try $.ui.activeDiv.attr("id") == "contents01" or simple javascript. if(document.getElementbyId("contents01)==true).

Comment: i will try soon and feedback here.thanks

Comment: ok try it and then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i get the ID, I am just wrapping it in a jqMobi object:

```
if( $($.ui.activeDiv).prop("id") == "someId" )
        //do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you just can do this

`$.ui.activeDiv.id == "contents01";`